# Space issues and rooting

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rooting, app2sd, internal-storage, huawei-u8150

I have a Huawei IDEOS u8150 running Froyo. Ever since I got this device, I've been running into low disk space problems (because of only 150 MB internal space). So I've had enough and moved all the apps I can to SD card. Then again, some were not movable.

So I did a little research and saw [this article on loading apps to the SD card by default](http://androidadvices.com/how-to-move-applications-to-sd-card-by-default/). It seemed to work rather weirdly, as some apps which couldn't be moved to the SD card before, now can be moved after using that trick. Still, the system apps and vendor bundled apps remained in the internal memory. Also, most of the moved apps still took some space on the internal memory.

The Froyo's app2sd rather seems to be behaving oddly according to me (though I've searched online and found this is normal, sadly).

**What I want to know is :**

1. Will rooting enable me to further enhance my Froyo's app2sd function?
2. Will custom mods be a better option with space management for my phone? If so, which ones?
3. Right now I have apps that I really need and use and I'm stuck with low disk space. (Please dont link me to anywhere; I've done all I can with cleared caches and I have no more apps to uninstall which I don't need.) I've heard that z4root takes 22MB+ internal space. Is there anything else to root using adb or something that wont require internal space? Or if I use z4root itself, can I remove the app fully after rooting and still have root? What about SuperOneClick's space cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never been a fan of the froyo apps2sd, I was a huge fan of the original "apps2sd" that used an EXT2/3/4 partition on your sdcard. I am not sure if any custom ROMs still support this. I know it is not "supported" in cyanogenMod. You will have to root to go the "apps2ext" route. but if you dont want to go that route, or can't find any ROMs that support it, I don't really know of any way you can really free up any additional space.

If rooted, you can delete any "bloatware" that is installed on the /system. You can remove z4root after you install it. Another thing to keep in mind, even if you install applications on the sdcard, they can still use the /data directory to store their data, which is located on the devices internal storage.

Comment: does app2ext have a function that moves /data/ to SDcard?

Comment: not that I am aware of.

Comment: ok,anyways, did you imply that the "original" app2sd (app2ext) was more effective than froyo's?

Comment: And actually, i'd like to keep my system apps but since its entirely on phone space right now, do you think it will be app2sd enabled once I root my phone? I really need to consider this as im in a dilemma of keeping my warranty.

Comment: just rooting it will not give you the "apps2ext" option, you will have to find a custom ROM or script that will enable it.

Comment: Some apps2ext scripts do have the option of moving dalvik-cache and /data/data/ to SD Card as well.  The most well known one is DarkTremor: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=715940  It's designed for the Nexus One phone, so I'd be careful and ask the developer if it will work on your handset.